run redis insight in cluster with default connection
I need to run an instance of Redis Insight for each of my users in a dashboard that I'm developing; these instances are created on Kubernetes and are able to see a Redis server.
I want to improve my user experience by automatically creating the connection to the database that is related to each user, so when their instance of Redis Insight is up, they are able to use their database instantly.
I didn't find a way to do this. I looked for a config file, or anything else in the container to find a way, but I failed.
Is there any way to satisfy my need?
Also it would be great if I can hide initial banner where asks user to accept license agreements.

discussed the status of this request and a current workaround there - https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight/issues/3324
